# MySQL query, order by numeric difference?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to do something like this:

```
    SELECT * FROM `sometable` 
    WHERE `smth`=`smth` 
    ORDER BY (`r1`-`r2`)
```

but when r2>r1, difference is not negative, and it has a very big value... How to get negative value after subtraction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well, I supose that you have unsigned values in r1 and r2... to get negative values try running this:

```
SET sql_mode='NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION';
```

Comment: If I run the above statement in my query box then will `sql_mode` permanently set to `NO_UNSIGNED_SUBSTRACTION` or it will be only for one query?

Comment: if you will execute this query, the parameter will be enabled only for the current connection ;]

Answer (score 0):

Is the fields unsigned possibly, if so it cannot be negative and you would have to cast the fields to normal int first.

Comment: yeap.. good idea... but this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286767/mysql-query-order-by-numeric-difference/4286776#4286776 is much simplier...